# Exclude parts of the document from the 'part'-counter

Tags: chapters, counters, parts

I have a problem regarding the 'part'counter. I have an MWE (i dont know if its satisfactory):

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage[a4paper, total={6.5in, 9in}]{geometry}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{titlesec}

    \addto\captionsdanish{
        \renewcommand*\appendixname{Bilag}
        \renewcommand\contentsname{Indholdsfortegnelse}
        \renewcommand\partname{Fase}
        \renewcommand\appendixpagename{Bilag}
        \renewcommand\appendixtocname{Bilag}
        \renewcommand\cftchaptername{Kapitel~}
        \renewcommand\cftappendixname{\appendixname~}
    }


    \renewcommand{\thepart}{Fase \arabic{part}}
    \titleformat{\part}
        [display]

    {\centering\fontfamily{pbk}\fontseries{m}\fontshape{n}\selectfont\Huge}
        {\MakeUppercase{\thepart}}
        {1pc}
        {\titlerule[2pt]\vspace{1pc}\huge\MakeUppercase}

    \makeatletter
    \@addtoreset{chapter}{part}
    \makeatother

    \definecolor{numbercolor}{gray}{0.7}
    \newif\ifchapternonum

    \makechapterstyle{jenor}{
        \renewcommand\beforechapskip{0pt}
        \renewcommand\printchaptername{}
        \renewcommand\printchapternum{}
        \renewcommand\printchapternonum{\chapternonumtrue}
        \renewcommand\chaptitlefont{
            \fontfamily{pbk}
            \fontseries{db}
            \fontshape{n}
            \fontsize{25}{35}
            \selectfont
            \raggedright
        }

        \renewcommand\chapnumfont{
            \fontfamily{pbk}
            \fontseries{m}
            \fontshape{n}
            \fontsize{1in}{0in}
            \selectfont\color{numbercolor}
        }
        \renewcommand\printchaptertitle[1]{%
            \noindent
        \ifchapternonum
            \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X}
                {\let\\\newline\chaptitlefont ##1\par}
            \end{tabularx}
            \par\vskip-2.5mm\hrule
        \else
            \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{Xl}
                {\parbox[b]{\linewidth}{\chaptitlefont ##1}} & 
        \raisebox{-15pt}{\chapnumfont \arabic{part}.\thechapter}
        \end{tabularx}
        \par\vskip2mm\hrule
        \fi
    \vspace{-20pt}
    }

}

\chapterstyle{jenor}    

\begin{document}

\part{first part}
\chapter{first chapter in first part}
\chapter{second chapter in first part}


\part{second part}
\chapter{first chapter in second part}
\chapter{second chapter in second part}

\appendix
\chapter{first appendix}
\chapter{second appendix}
\chapter{third appendix}

\end{document}
```

This is how it looks now:

> Part 1 First part
>
> Chapter 1.1 First chapter of first part
>
> Chapter 1.2 Second chapter of first part
>
> Part 2 Second part
>
> Chapter 2.1 First chapter of second part
>
> Chapter 2.2 Second chapter of second part
>
> Appendix 2.A First appendix
>
> Appendix 2.B second appendix
>
> Appendix 2.C third appendix

Now, what I wanted it to do is to not number the 'part' when the Appendix start, so it looks like this:

> Part 1 First part
>
> Chapter 1.1 First chapter of first part
>
> Chapter 1.2 Second chapter of first part
>
> Part 2 Second part
>
> Chapter 2.1 First chapter of second part
>
> Chapter 2.2 Second chapter of second part
>
> Appendix A First appendix
>
> Appendix B second appendix
>
> Appendix C third appendix

I have tried resetting the counter, but that just replaces the 2 with a 0

I know that the obvious solution is to not have the `\arabic{part}` in the if/else argument in the chapter definition, but all the other chapters have to have the part-counter included.

Comment: Redefine \thechapter to be `\arabic{part}.\arabic{chapter}`, and use \thechapter in your definition. Then you can redefine it again before the appendix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage[a4paper, total={6.5in, 9in}]{geometry}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{titlesec}


    \addto\captionsdanish{
        \renewcommand*\appendixname{Bilag}
        \renewcommand\contentsname{Indholdsfortegnelse}
        \renewcommand\partname{Fase}
        \renewcommand\appendixpagename{Bilag}
        \renewcommand\appendixtocname{Bilag}
        \renewcommand\cftchaptername{Kapitel~}
        \renewcommand\cftappendixname{\appendixname~}
    }


    \renewcommand{\thepart}{Fase \arabic{part}}
    \titleformat{\part}
        [display]
    {\centering\fontfamily{pbk}\fontseries{m}\fontshape{n}\selectfont\Huge}
        {\MakeUppercase{\thepart}}
        {1pc}
        {\titlerule[2pt]\vspace{1pc}\huge\MakeUppercase}

    \makeatletter
    \@addtoreset{chapter}{part}
    \makeatother

    \definecolor{numbercolor}{gray}{0.7}
    \newif\ifchapternonum

    \makechapterstyle{jenor}{
        \renewcommand\beforechapskip{0pt}
        \renewcommand\printchaptername{}
        \renewcommand\printchapternum{}
        \renewcommand\printchapternonum{\chapternonumtrue}
        \renewcommand\chaptitlefont{
            \fontfamily{pbk}
            \fontseries{db}
            \fontshape{n}
            \fontsize{25}{35}
            \selectfont
            \raggedright
        }

        \renewcommand\chapnumfont{
            \fontfamily{pbk}
            \fontseries{m}
            \fontshape{n}
            \fontsize{1in}{0in}
            \selectfont\color{numbercolor}
        }
        \renewcommand\printchaptertitle[1]{%
            \noindent
        \ifchapternonum
            \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X}
                {\let\\\newline\chaptitlefont ##1\par}
            \end{tabularx}
            \par\vskip-2.5mm\hrule
        \else
            \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{Xl}
                {\parbox[b]{\linewidth}{\chaptitlefont ##1}} & 
        \raisebox{-15pt}{\chapnumfont \mychapter}
        \end{tabularx}
        \par\vskip2mm\hrule
        \fi
    \vspace{-20pt}
    }

}

\newcommand{\mychapter}{\arabic{part}.\thechapter}

\let\oldappendix\appendix

\def\appendix{\renewcommand{\mychapter}{\thechapter}\oldappendix}

\chapterstyle{jenor}    

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{first part}
\chapter{first chapter in first part}
\chapter{second chapter in first part}


\part{second part}
\chapter{first chapter in second part}
\chapter{second chapter in second part}

\appendix
\chapter{first appendix}
\chapter{second appendix}
\chapter{third appendix}

\end{document}
```

Actually is very close to @UlrikeFischer's suggestion, but somehow automated.

**Explanation:**

1. The line: `\newcommand{\mychapter}{\arabic{part}.\thechapter}` is just a newcommand that will be used to appear the chapter in the desired format in any case... Initially it is exactly like your definition in your MWE.
2. The lines:

   `\let\oldappendix\appendix`

   `\def\appendix{\renewcommand{\mychapter}{\thechapter}\oldappendix}`

   just adding to the definition of `\appendix` command the REdefinition of the command \mychapter to include just `\thechapter` (getting rid of `\arabic{part}` of its previous definition)... So, every new `\chapter` command after appendix will show only `\thechapter` (but from the old definition of `\appendix` command -already used in our new definition of it- `\thechapter` is already redefined to `\Aplh{chapter}` and this is enough for your requirements).

Comment: This works! I'm interested in what the different codes do, can you maybe explain the 3 lines you added?

Comment: @L.Nielsen ... Added some explanation in the answer ... Feel free to ask whatever you don't understand.